# Multithreading Face-recognition python

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I am trying to use 2 threads in python to solve face-recognition task. The first thread is used to capture frame and append it into deque, and the second one is used to read the frame from deque to solve face-recognition task, deque is a global variable .When i start 2 threads, it show the result as below.
[This is result of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSnUo.png). In second thread, process function don't execute.

and here is my code. How to when a new frame is appended into deque in first thread, and the second thread is detect and recognize the face in new frame.

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
from threading import Thread
from collections import deque
import pickle

svm = pickle.load(open('svm.pkl','rb'))

deque = deque()
def open_camera(url):
    print('start camera')
    #capture = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://'+str(url))
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while capture.isOpened():
        _,frame = capture.read()
        frame_resize = cv2.resize(frame,(640,480))
        cv2.imshow('Video',frame_resize)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
            break
        # cvtColor
        frame_resize = frame_resize[:, :, ::-1]
        deque.append(frame_resize)

    capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
def spin(seconds):
    time.sleep(seconds)
def process_camera():
    print("start process")
    global deque
    if deque:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print(deque[-1])
        for i in deque:
            process(frame=i)
    else:
        for i in deque:
            process(frame=i)
def process(frame):
    print('process')
    frame = cv2.imread(frame)
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(frame)
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(frame,face_locations)
    face_names = []
    for face_encoding in face_encodings:
        name = svm.predict(face_encoding.reshape(1, -1))
        face_names.append(name)
    print(face_names)

thread1= Thread(target=open_camera, args=(0,))
thread2 = Thread(target=process_camera, args=())
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
print('\texit main')
```

Thanks you so much!